# Need help trying to combine two data panels. Display 0 if corresponding cell is also 0

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to combine two data panels. Illustrated in this picture

[image]

my data currently looks like the left and middle panel. I would like to combine them two to get the right panel.

Please note there are missing years in my middle panel (e.g. Company A - 2011). If the value of "Name" is "0", then the corresponding "Number" in the new panel would also be "0".

Cheers.

Comment: tell us what you have tried. have you tried recording a macro and modifying it? how good are you with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA for that. You could do it in one step but it'd be a lot less clear. Let's start:

- Insert a column left of column A. In that new cell A2 we will create a unique primary key by using the formula: `=A2&B2`. Drag and drop to fill column A
- In cell J2: `=G2&H2`. Drag and drop to fill column J
- In Column E, we'll get the information from table 2. We will use INDEX and MATCH to lookup on the primary key. It is the same idea as VLOOKUP except here we're doing a left lookup.
  INDEX(range, row, column) returns the value in the range that is at the intersection of the row and column you specify. MATCH returns the position of a value in an array. We'll also use an IFERROR statement to return 0 if it doesn't exist in table 2

In Cell E2: `=INDEX($I:$J,MATCH($A2,$J:$J,0),1)` . Let's add the IFERROR statement as well

E2 : `=IFERROR(INDEX($I:$J,MATCH($A2,$J:$J,0),1),"0")`

There you go!

[image: Layout of the worksheet]